# Multiple elastic instances on same host

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to test elastic replication and install multiple elastic instances on the same host.

I've created an additional elastic search configuration file and set the following config property:

```
http.port: 9500
```

The other elastic search configuration file contains the default value :

```
http.port: 9200
```

I attempt to start elastic using :

./bin/elasticsearch -Ees.config=./config/elasticsearch.yml

but receive error :

```
uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [es.config] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
```

How to utilize 2 elasticsearch instances on the same host ?

Is there an alternative to the `es.config` parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ES_PATH_CONF=/path/to/my/config ./bin/elasticsearch
```

This is the way to do it according to the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html (depending on the version you are using, it might differ).

I would recommend using a docker setup for this endeavour as described here (official elasticsearch documentation) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Alkis Kalogeris already stated, I would also recommend using docker/docker-compose. You would just need to expose a different port to your localhost.